# Evaluation of where clause in cyclic lists

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming

In *Thinking Functionally in Haskell* (p 213), we're shown two versions of a cyclic list. One evaluates in quadratic time:

```
iterate3 f x = x:map f (iterate3 f x)

iterate3 (2*) 1
= 1:map (2*) (iterate3 (2*) 1)
= 1:2:map (2*) (map (2*) (iterate3 (2*) 1))
= 1:2:4:map (2*) (map (2*) (map (2*) (iterate3 (2*) 1)))
```

The other, which uses `where`, evaluates in linear time:

```
iterate2 f x = xs where xs = x:map f xs

iterate2 (2*) 1    
xs          where xs = 1:map (2*) xs
= 1:ys      where ys = map (2*) (1:ys)
= 1:2:zs    where zs = map (2*) (2:zs)
= 1:2:4:ts  where ts = map (2*) (4:ts)
```

I don't quite understand this evaluation. How is x getting reassigned to each successive list element, instead of 1 (as in the first version)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The important detail is that `xs` in `iterate2` is defined in terms of itself, creating a circular structure.
(This is sometimes called "tying the knot".)

Visualizing it as a graph, the evaluation goes something like this (warning: ASCII art).

`xs where xs = 1 : map (2*) xs`:

```
     :  <----------+
   /   \           | applies to
  1    map (2*)  --+
```

`-->`

```
     :
   /   \
  1     :  <--------+   
      /   \         | applies to
     2   map (2*) --+
```

`-->`

```
     :
   /   \
  1     : 
      /   \
     2     : <---------+
         /   \         | applies to
        4   map (2*) --+
```

And so on.

Comment: Thank you! For me, finding the right visualization is often the biggest obstacle to understanding a recursion.

Comment: One follow-up question: Does iterate3 produce a cyclic list? The text is slightly ambiguous on this point.

Comment: @planarian I would say that the list itself doesn't have any cycles – no matter how much of it you evaluate, you will not "come back" to a previous element – but you could claim that its definition has one. (That is, it's a "cyclic definition of a list" but not "a definition of a cyclical list".)

Answer (score 1):

Let's unroll the recursion in `iterate2`:

```
xs = x : map f xs
   = x : map f (x : map f xs)                          -- Inline xs
   = x : (f x) : map f (map f xs)                      -- Definition of map
   = x : (f x) : map f (map f (x : map f xs))          -- Inline xs
   = x : (f x) : map f ((f x) : map f (map f xs))      -- Definition of map
   = x : (f x) : (f (f x)) : map f (map f (map f xs))) -- Definition of map
   ...
```

So you can see that the list returned by `iterate2 f x` has `x` as the first element, `f x` as the second, and so on.

Comment: This reduction is semantically correct, but fails to show that this is computed in linear time -- we still have a quadratic complexity in this reduction. This might confuse the OP.

Comment: Right, but I don't know how I'd show that while still answering the original question of how `x` is "updated".